# KDE task bar not recognizing the .desktop file

Tags: kde, desktop-environments, .desktop, plasma-5

I  have Ubuntu 18.04 with Plasma 5 desktop. I'm a programmer, and I have a question about a rare situation.

I have a desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/xapp.desktop` with a content like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Icon=org-xapp
Type=Application
Categories=Development;

Exec=/home/james/Electron/dist/electron /home/james/path-to-electron-app
MimeType=
Name=XAPP
Comment=
#NoDisplay=true
```

Well, the app is shown in the applications menu and opens perfectly, but when I pin it to the taskbar in KDE, the executable is pinned without the full command present in desktop file. I expected that it would be pinned with the full command line of the desktop file.

I see that Chrome applications are pinned correctly, and the desktop file of these apps doesn't have nothing special.

What is the reason of my custom app not getting pinned correctly? How can I get it pinned correctly on Plasma 5 KDE?

Comment: Why do you have `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open`? Is that needed? And why the repitition here: `Exec=/home/james/Electron/dist/electron /home/james/path-to-electron-app`?

Comment: I see that line on others desktop file. I know that is for execute desktop file directly. However let me check removing.

Comment: Sorry you have reason, I delete and make again my comment to explain correctly why is the line added. I copy from another desktop file, just now don't remember what. However I checked without that line, and still have problem

Comment: In any case, you can also try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php/242-KDE-neon), or [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/) or [reddit/kubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/). There maybe users there who could help!

Answer (score 0):

After many tests I found why is not recognized. 
However I still think it's a strange behavior, and make difficult distribute applications. Ok, for a correct perspective, I will show all my tests.

My app will be based on electron, so I tried this:

1. `~/electron@6.0.11` with the electron dist content and `~/developer/electron-quick-start` with an electron example app
2. `ln -s ~/electron-6.0.11 ~/Electron` symbolic link to folder
3. A bash `/home/james/execute` file with content:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
/home/james/electron-6.0.11/electron /home/james/developer/electron-quick-start
```

Now I will show the different desktop files that I tried:

1. NOT WORKING. Applications opens, but KDE taskbar doesn't recognize the desktop file, so cannot be pinned correctly. The reason is because executable directory in desktop file is symlinked

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Icon=org-xapp
....
Exec=/home/james/Electron/electron /home/james/developer/electron-quick-start
...
```

2. NOT WORKING. Same as before

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Icon=org-xapp
....
Exec="/home/james/Electron/electron" /home/james/developer/electron-quick-start
...
```

3. WORKING. Using the real canonical path, instead of symlink is recognized by KDE taskbar.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Icon=org-xapp
....
Exec=/home/james/electron-6.0.11/electron /home/james/developer/electron-quick-start
...
```

4. NOT WORKING. App opens, but KDE taskbar cannot recognize the desktop file. I am using the canonical path like previous example, but no getting recognized due to '"' scaping in executable. From my perspective this is a wrong behavior from KDE.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Icon=org-xapp
....
Exec="/home/james/electron-6.0.11/electron" /home/james/developer/electron-quick-start
...
```

5. NOT WORKING. Adding environment variables to exec, make KDE taskbar doesn't recognize the desktop file. So again, I think that is a wrong behavior from KDE taskbar.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Icon=org-xapp
....
Exec=env MYVAR=1 /home/james/electron-6.0.11/electron /home/james/developer/electron-quick-start
...
```

6. NOT WORKING. App opens, but not getting recognized the desktop. Setting a bash (or another filetype that uses child_process) to call the original arguments, causes KDE taskbar not recognize the file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Icon=org-xapp
....
Exec=/home/james/execute
...
```

Ok, my opinion: behavior 6 is acceptable and understable, behavior 1 and 2 is questionable (Is not there way to know if points to same file?), behavior 4 and 5 is unnaceptable and from my perspective is wrong, KDE taskbar should recognize the desktop file in this cases.